# If needed, if necessary and if any

Tags: idiomatic-language, if

I would like to know how to use "if needed", "if necessary" and "if any".

Like can I say "Please give me advices if needed"; "Please give me advices if any"?

But I find these two a bit awkward. Please help improve the sentences and explain the use of the three phrases.

Comment: Separately, it should be "give me *advice*" - "advice" isn't countable, and can't be made plural

Comment: Oh. Yes. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: If [it is] needed - if [it is] necessary- if [there are] any.